# Battery power options for ESP-01 + Sensor (Arduino Project)

Tags: arduino, power-supply, sensor

I am building out my first self-designed project and am a bit unsure how to proceed with the power setup. I'm making a sensor device that will send me a tweet whenever the relative moisture of my plant gets low. I plan on making one for each potted plant in the house (a dozen or so), so want to keep things cheap and also not need to be near an outlet.

I have all the code working fine, but not sure what to do with regards to power. I am using an ESP8266-01 wifi module ([this](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B07H1W6DJZ) one) that has 8 pins (2 IO, TX, RX, 3.3V, GND, reset) with [this](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B07SYBSHGX) soil sensor, which need 3.3V, gnd, and output connect.

I guess I don't get how I can power both the ESP-01 and the sensor. I don't want to use a full Uno or something, to keep the price minimal. So much I see online seems to say I should be able to use just these two components. But I don't see how.

I have a bunch of [adafruit trinket m0](https://www.adafruit.com/product/3500) boards, which give me battery/usb in, but only one 3.3V out. So, I could set the code up to use the trinket as the control that reads the sensor and then passes the readings to the ESP-01. But there aren't enough power outs on the trinket?

Should i set up two battery supplies, one for the wifi and one for the sensor, or can I somehow combine the two off the one 3.3V output from the trinket?

Total newbie on power setup, so please forgive if these are dumb questions.

EDIT: To clarify, per the comments:

In an "ideal" world, the ESP-01 wifi module would run the code that both reads the sensor and send the tweet containing the sensor data. If I could figure out how to both power the ESP-01 and the sensor without using the trinket, that would be what I would prefer.

Barring that, I would use the trinket to read the sensor, then use the trinket to send the data re: sensor data to ESP-01 to POST the tweet. Basically making the trinket the power hub, I guess.

If I can just set up a power source and splice the wires off to the ESP-01 and sensor, great. But would that work?

I assume I would need to use the trinket if I don't want to worry about stepping down power and whatnot, so would a splice still have enough power for both the 3.3V ESP-01 and the 3.3V sensor?

If so, for the future, how to I determine that?

Comment: Do you have a voltmeter? Can you confirm whether the trinket output power is 3V or 3.3V? And do you know how much current the wifi module and moisture sensors need? I assume the sensor doesn't need much but it would be nice to confirm. I believe the trinket can supply 150mA which is probably enough, although the wifi peak could be higher than that, maybe.

Comment: I do and will do in the morning (on the east coast us). I know it's rated for 3.3V, but I assume there's some variation in actual?

Comment: It is just that the label on the board says 3V. Not 3.3V. Yes, some variation is perfectly OK. But if it is closer to 3 than 3.3 the wifi might not work.